# Need help understanding the order of tracing code in a while loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

I am trying to trace the code of a while loop and I'm stuck. How do i deal with the !result. If result = false, then !result = true, so after the first loop, the result then = true. the next time the loop is repeated, does !result = false?

EDIT - what i'm really asking is after the first loop, will the result change? because at the end of the first loop the result is true, so the next time you reach !result does that make it false?

```
boolean result = false;
int i = 0;

while (i < arr.length && !result) {
    if (arr[i] == val) {
        result = true;
    }
    i++;
}
return result;
```

the array is {3, 7, -2, 8, 4}

Comment: The use of **!** in this regard is not the same as using the **Not** statement in other languages. It's more like this: `if (result) { .... }` is basically the same as `If(result is true) { ... }`. And:  `if (!result) { ... }` is basically the same as `If(result is false) { ... }`. To do something similar to the **Not** statement (which is not available in Java) so as to **toggle** the value of result from true to false or false to true, you would do: `result = !result;`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be re-written as

```
while (i < arr.length && result == false) {
    ..
}
```

Alternatively you could use a `break` within the `if`

```
while (i < arr.length ) {
  if (arr[i] == val) {
      result = true;
      break;
  }
  ....
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, except that i must also be incremented.

Comment: And i would not have the same value after the loop, but in this case, it doesn't matter.